# what is the best way to copy live data to staging with most recent important data

Tags: magento2.3, data-migration, copydata

I upgraded to 2.3.1 from 2.1.x copied the old site to new server and everything has been upgraded working!! I plan to change the DNS when ready. now i need to grab the most recent order and costumers info to go live. 
what are the most important data I can manually copy from live db? if there are 10-15 tables to copy data and dump would be ideal.

or is there way i can copy the whole site data and dump into the staging site???there has to be easier way? typical magento never make it easy...

Comment: I suggest to backup the DB, then push all files / DB to a private repository (github will allow you to use a free private repo. ) then you can clone the repo to your new server, the only thing you need is to change the Base URL in core_conifg_date table

Comment: that really not what i need. i copied all the file and db to new server - now i been testing everything fore few weeks - the live site has all the  new orders - i just want all that info updated into the testing db. thats all